# Creating keyboard hotkeys/shortcuts in Word with VBA

Tags: vba, keyboard-shortcuts, ms-word

For some reason my shortcuts in my normal.dotm files gets deleted once in a while,
so I know i can create shortcuts in word by clicking around in word (https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008058_Assigning_a_Macro_to_a_Shortcut_Key.html)

but I would like to hardcode them instead like I do in excel:

```
Sub keyBoardShortCuts()

    Application.OnKey "%^d", "updateDB"
    Application.OnKey "%^p", "openProjectList"
    Application.OnKey "%^m", "addNewLS"
    Application.OnKey "%^l", "createLS"
    Application.OnKey "%^g", "loadGui"
    Application.OnKey "%^b", "Custom_Button_Click"

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call keyBoardShortCuts
End Sub
```

However this does not work in word, so what is the syntax to do so in word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `KeyBindings` and the constants from `Enum WdKey`  (press F2 to see the list) :

```
With Application.KeyBindings
    .Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKeyControl, wdKeyD), _
         KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
         Command:="updateDB"
    .Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKeyControl, wdKeyP), _
         KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
         Command:="openProjectList"
    .Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyAlt, wdKeyControl, wdKeyM), _
         KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
         Command:="addNewLS"
    '...
End With 'Application.KeyBindings
```